# Default layout colour

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, colors, default

I'm wondering why, every time I create a new Android project, Eclipse opens a main activity with a white background, when in previous versions, it was black.
Is there any way for me to change that back to black as a default color for future activities?.

Answer (score 1):

They changed the default theme that eclipse uses in your resources to the light theme.  Change your resource files (delete the stuff eclipse added that you don't use) and it will go back to black.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to reskin your whole application to black, you can use following line in your manifest file.

Write to `Application` tag attribute `theme`.

```
<Application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" //old targeted application
    OR
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" //for new devices
    ... >
```

Now all activities in this application have black theme.

You can "override" this by using theme attribute in `Activity` tag.

```
<Activity
      android:theme="some theme"
      ...>
```